# How do I target a div when programmatically submitting and MVC Ajax form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm using the MVC4 Ajax helper functions on a form and I'd like to submit the form from script.

The problem is when I call the submit function, it does not load into the proper div.  Any thoughts?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewGame", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "targetDiv" }, new { id = "newGameForm" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="client_seed" id="client_seed" />
    <input type="submit" value="New Game" id="NewGameButton" />
    <a class=button onclick="$('#newGameForm').submit();">New Game</a> 
}
```

Clicking the standard submit button load the results of the call into the targetDiv.  Clicking on the anchor replaces the current div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to **prevent default browser behavior** via `.preventDefault()` or to `return false` at the end of the event handlers.

This is how I'd do it:

```
<div id="targetDiv"></div>
@using(Html.BeginForm("NewGame", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
    new { id = "newGameForm" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="client_seed" id="client_seed" />
    <input type="submit" value="New Game" id="NewGameButton" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#newGameForm").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: $(this).attr("method")  // "POST"
        })
        .done(function(result) {
            $("#targetDiv").html(result);
        })
        .fail(function((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // handle error
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

If you insist on using an anchor `<a>`...

```
<a href="#" class="button" id="submit-link">New Game</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit-link").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#newGameForm").submit();
    });

    $("#newGameForm").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        ...
    });
});
</script>
```

**Edit** There is also an [AjaxHelper.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493106%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method. If you're already using the `AjaxHelper` in other parts of your code you might want to stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code.

```
<a class=button onclick="PostAjax();">New Game</a>

function PostAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"Home/NewGame",
        data:$('#newGameForm').serialize(),
        DataType:"HTML", // assuming your post method returns HTML
        success:function(data){
            $("#targetDiv").html(data);
        },
        error:function(err){
            alert(err);
        }
    })
}
```